# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in function

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, appendchild

I have seen many questions about this error but, I haven’t found the answer on any of them.

I’m creating an interactive page to create patterns based on geometric shapes and I’m having problems adding a new element with a function that creates a new element and adds the element to a “base” div. Then, the base div is cloned to create the pattern.

In the HTML I’ve created a color picker to preselect the color before creating the element, and a button that contains a function to create and append the new element to the base div.

Also in the HTML, I created the SVG shapes with a “display:none” style, and when I retrieve them with JS, I just change it to “display:block”.

I can append many elements with javascript instructions (there are some examples in the code), but when I put these instructions inside a function, the code doesn’t work and I got the error: “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null”

This is my code, I included comments for easier reading. Hope you can help me.

```js
//Global variables
var picker = document.getElementById('picker');
var color = picker.value;


//Base elements
var myRow = document.getElementById("row");
var myDiv = document.createElement("base");
myDiv.className = 'base';


// Retrieves the 'out_circle' SVG from HTML and defines properties
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("out_circle");
innerDiv.style.display = "block";
innerDiv.style.fill = "#3c00ff";
innerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
// Adds the element to the base div
myDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

// Retrieves the 'sqr_small' SVG from HTML and defines properties
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("sqr_small");
innerDiv.style.display = "block";
innerDiv.style.fill = "purple";
innerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
innerDiv.style.margin = "5";
// Adds the element to the base div
myDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

// Retrieves the 'diamond' SVG from HTML and defines properties
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("diamond");
innerDiv.style.display = "block";
innerDiv.style.fill = "green";
innerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
// Adds the element to the base div
myDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

// Retrieves the 'slash_right' SVG from HTML and defines properties
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("slash_right");
innerDiv.style.display = "block";
innerDiv.style.fill = "orange";
innerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
// Adds the element to the base div
myDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);


//*****NOT WORKING FUNCTION*****
function create_Lslash() {
  // Retrieves the 'slash_left' SVG from HTML and defines properties
  var innerDiv = document.getElementById("slash_left");
  innerDiv.style.display = "block";
  innerDiv.style.fill = color;
  innerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  // Adds the element to base div
  myDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
}



// Clones the div to create a row
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  myRow.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
  i++;
}

//Clones the row to create a grid
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  document.body.appendChild(myRow.cloneNode(true));
  i++;
}
```

```css
/* a minimalist set of CSS resets */


/* default to border-box */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* adjust typography defaults */

body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.base {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/favicon.ico" />
  <title>Patterns</title>
  <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
  <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Color picker  -->
  <div style="padding:40px 0 0 0;">
    <input type="color" id="picker" value="#0000ff">
  </div>
  <!-- "Create" button  -->
  <div style="padding:40px 0 40px 0;">
    <button id="creator" onclick="create_Lslash()">Create</button>
  </div>
  <div id="row" class="row"></div>
  <!-- Elements to append  -->
  <div>
    <!-- Diamond  -->
    <svg id="diamond" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewbox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50; display:none;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <rect x="7.32" y="7.32" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -10.3553 25)" class="st0" width="35.36" height="35.36"/>
      </svg>
    <!-- Out_circle  -->
    <svg id="out_circle" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewbox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50; display:none;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <defs>
        </defs>
        <g>
          <path class="st0" d="M25,50h25V25C50,38.81,38.81,50,25,50z"/>
          <path class="st0" d="M25,0c13.81,0,25,11.19,25,25V0H25z"/>
          <path class="st0" d="M0,25v25h25C11.19,50,0,38.81,0,25z"/>
          <path class="st0" d="M25,0H0v25C0,11.19,11.19,0,25,0z"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    <!-- Small square  -->
    <svg id="sqr_small" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="40px" viewbox="0 0 40 40" style="enable-background:new 0 0 40 40; display:none;" xml:space="preserve">
        <defs>
        </defs>
        <rect width="40" height="40"/>
      </svg>
    <!-- Right slash  -->
    <svg id="slash_right" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewbox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50; display:none;" xml:space="preserve">
          <defs>
          </defs>
          <g>
              <polygon class="st0" points="6.36,0 0,0 0,6.36 43.64,50 50,50 50,43.64    " />
          </g>
      </svg>
    <!-- Left slash  -->
    <svg id="slash_left" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewbox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50; display:none;" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
      </defs>
      <g>
        <polygon class="st0" points="0,43.64 0,50 6.36,50 50,6.36 50,0 43.64,0  "/>
      </g>
      </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears when you click the **Create** button second time.

The function `create_Lslash()` calls `myDiv.appendChild(innerDiv)`. As `innerDiv` here is an existing element `svg#slash_left`, it is moved from it's current position to new position (child of `myDiv`). But you don't append `myDiv` back to the html document after this.

Hence, `svg#slash_left` is not found in the document when you click **Create** again and `var innerDiv = document.getElementById("slash_left");` evaluates to `null`.

Ref: [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Thanks @Amith ! With your suggestion, I don't see the error anymore, but when I append myDiv to the HTML, it just adds the new Div to the row and the rest of the pattern shows the previous version of the Div. I'm trying to figure out how to "replace" the div, once it's updated. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @EdgarPaniagua I'm not sure what you are trying to do, you might as well ask a new question with your updated code for it.